# how to use pybrain weights to predict

Tags: python, neural-network, pybrain

I want to know how does pybrain give the predicition according the weight.
For example, I have specified

```
network=buildNetwork(traindata.indim, 4, traindata.outdim, 
            hiddenclass = TanhLayer, outclass= TanhLayer).
```

Suppose I know the weights of this trained network, how can I do the prediciton myself? I need to calculate the result in another program using Java. Or what is the activate function of this network?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Is pybrain an open-source library? Have you checked the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For different layer activation functions meaning, just google `tanh activation function`. [One of the links](http://www.heatonresearch.com/wiki/Activation_Function), containing java implementation details.

If you're not familar with neueral network computations, pleas refer to [*NEURAL NETWORKS*](http://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/~nd/surprise_96/journal/vol4/cs11/report.html)

There are lot of different already built NN libraries for almost all programming languages. Here is [one for java](http://neuroph.sourceforge.net/).